# Split by first space only using lua

Tags: string, lua

I am trying this to split string from first space..

```
s = 'Canada Japan Australia'
l = s.split(' ', 1)
ShowInfo(" l :" .. l)
```

but I'm getting an error.

I want something like this

```
s = Canada Japan Australia

a = Canada
b = Japan Australia
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `string.split` function in Lua. However, this is pretty easy to achieve using [`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match):

```lua
local s = "Canada Japan Australia"
local a, b = s:match"^(%S+)%s+(.+)" -- capture one or more non-space characters, then expect one or more spaces, capture all remaining characters
assert(a)
```

Please refer to the [Lua reference manual's section on patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1).